# For Loop Giving More Values Then Should(java android)

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

I have a json array like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "11",
    "notes": "edgbdefgbfffffffffffffffffffff",
    "start_date": "2015-04-28",
    "end_date": "2015-04-29",
    "user_id": "66",
    "status": "1",
    "from_country": "Armenia",
    "from_state": "Aragatsotn",
    "from_city": "Aragatsotn",
    "from_street": "Avan Road",
    "from_apt": "",
    "from_longitude": "44.174652099609375",
    "from_latitude": "40.35805621890491",
    "from_place_id": "ChIJq1tZBgOJakAR79py0zHBCVo",
    "to_country": "Armenia",
    "to_state": "Yerevan",
    "to_city": "Yerevan",
    "to_street": "Tsitsernakaberd Highway",
    "to_apt": "",
    "to_longitude": "44.487762451171875",
    "to_latitude": "40.18097176388719",
    "to_place_id": "ChIJJcq4GKm9akARQboxrm84dHY",
    "creator_first_name": "Poxos1s",
    "creator_last_name": "Poxosyan",
    "creator_paypal_email": null,
    "creator_credit_card": null,
    "creator_phone": "374 99 99 99 99",
    "creator_email": "poxos@gmail.com",
    "creator_file_id": "163",
    "from_country_short": "AM",
    "to_country_short": "AM"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "notes": "rtyerty",
    "start_date": "2015-04-24",
    "end_date": "2015-04-25",
    "user_id": "61",
    "status": "1",
    "from_country": "Armenia",
    "from_state": "Aragatsotn",
    "from_city": "Aragatsotn",
    "from_street": "H20",
    "from_apt": "",
    "from_longitude": "44.219970703125",
    "from_latitude": "40.46157664398329",
    "from_place_id": "ChIJ23CVRId-akARPsgD3Zt77bI",
    "to_country": "Armenia",
    "to_state": "Armavir",
    "to_city": "Armavir",
    "to_street": "M-3 M-3",
    "to_apt": "",
    "to_longitude": "44.3243408203125",
    "to_latitude": "40.204050425113294",
    "to_place_id": "EhBNLTMgTS0zLCBBcm1lbmlh",
    "creator_first_name": "Hovsep",
    "creator_last_name": "Markosyan",
    "creator_paypal_email": null,
    "creator_credit_card": null,
    "creator_phone": "077310128",
    "creator_email": "markosyanhoso@mail.ru",
    "creator_file_id": "263",
    "from_country_short": "AM",
    "to_country_short": "AM"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "notes": "ghjgh",
    "start_date": "2015-04-22",
    "end_date": "2015-04-24",
    "user_id": "66",
    "status": "1",
    "from_country": "Armenia",
    "from_state": "Aragatsotn",
    "from_city": "Aragatsotn",
    "from_street": "Factory Street",
    "from_apt": "",
    "from_longitude": "44.32708740234375",
    "from_latitude": "40.33188951824973",
    "from_place_id": "ChIJF--_mNmEakARLtYmVplqp7c",
    "to_country": "Armenia",
    "to_state": "Armavir",
    "to_city": "Armavir",
    "to_street": "Unnamed Road",
    "to_apt": "",
    "to_longitude": "44.263916015625",
    "to_latitude": "40.19041398364302",
    "to_place_id": "ChIJ01kFw2eTakARVNQCrG2iewg",
    "creator_first_name": "Poxos1s",
    "creator_last_name": "Poxosyan",
    "creator_paypal_email": null,
    "creator_credit_card": null,
    "creator_phone": "374 99 99 99 99",
    "creator_email": "poxos@gmail.com",
    "creator_file_id": "163",
    "from_country_short": "AM",
    "to_country_short": "AM"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "notes": "yky",
    "start_date": "2015-04-23",
    "end_date": "2015-04-30",
    "user_id": "60",
    "status": "1",
    "from_country": "Armenia",
    "from_state": "Yerevan",
    "from_city": "Yerevan",
    "from_street": "3 Agatangeghos Street",
    "from_apt": "",
    "from_longitude": "44.510765075683594",
    "from_latitude": "40.170872380088376",
    "from_place_id": "ChIJ58PEYFi8akARtejTCFF4jOk",
    "to_country": "Armenia",
    "to_state": "Yerevan",
    "to_city": "Yerevan",
    "to_street": "Kond Street",
    "to_apt": "",
    "to_longitude": "44.502010345458984",
    "to_latitude": "40.18215211323218",
    "to_place_id": "ChIJa_8u6AG9akARK2k5uMHdgJ8",
    "creator_first_name": "Miqo",
    "creator_last_name": "Dallaqyan",
    "creator_paypal_email": "ssdfsd@sdfsdf.sda",
    "creator_credit_card": "1234 5678 9123 4564",
    "creator_phone": "12345677",
    "creator_email": "aaa@aa.aa",
    "creator_file_id": "247",
    "from_country_short": "AM",
    "to_country_short": "AM"
  }

 .......................

]
```

and I'm looping through array in this way:

```
 try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(roadsresponse);
        Log.d("roadsresponse",roadsresponse);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
            roadstolongitude = row.getString("to_longitude");
            roadstolatitude = row.getString("to_latitude");
            roadsfirstname = row.getString("creator_first_name");
            roadslastname = row.getString("creator_last_name");
            roadsstartdate = row.getString("start_date");
            roadsenddate = row.getString("end_date");
            roadsfromplace = row.getString("from_country");
            roadstoplace = row.getString("to_country");
            roadsfromcity = row.getString("from_city");
            roadstocity = row.getString("to_city");
            roadsnotes = row.getString("notes");
            roadsfromlatitude = row.getString("from_latitude");
            roadsfromlongitude = row.getString("from_longitude");
            double tolongdouble = Double.parseDouble(roadstolongitude);
            double tolatdouble = Double.parseDouble(roadstolatitude);
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position(new LatLng(tolatdouble, tolongdouble));
            options.title("roads");
            options.rotation(1);
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.roads));
            options.snippet(roadsfirstname + "/" + roadslastname + "/" + roadsstartdate + "/" + roadsenddate + "/" + roadsfromplace + "/" + roadsfromcity + "/" + roadstoplace + "/" + roadstocity + "/" + roadsnotes + "/" + roadsfromlongitude + "/" + roadsfromlatitude + "/" + roadstolongitude + "/" + roadstolatitude);
            map2.addMarker(options);
            Log.d("toplace",roadstoplace);
```

You can see that I'm printing the `roadstoplace`, and I'm receiving this kind of print

```
 05-11 11:37:02.937  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.938  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.940  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.942  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.944  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.945  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.947  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.949  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.951  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ Armenia
05-11 11:37:02.953  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ null
05-11 11:37:02.955  13832-13832/com.paqqy D/toplace﹕ null
```

First I though it's normal and there should be 11 elements in the array, but when I manually started to count, I got to point that I have 9 elements and last 2 `NULL` elements just came from nowhere.... So whats the problem about it? Do I do anything wrong in the loop? I should receive then 9 elements instead of 11, but I do receive 11 elements and most funny is that last 2 elements are `null`....please do help me!

Comment: can you post the URL here??

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on Json parsing in Java, but it looks like a Json Object, not an array. I think you should use JSONObject

Comment: unfortunatally i cant as its not public local server and its hidden,i only get response when i send POST request with fixed parameters...

Comment: but you can see full json response which i did post

Comment: unfortunatally your wrong as its JSONarray:( explanation: "["=json array, "{"=json object

Comment: please may you post the whole JSON, possibly well formatted, thus we can inspect it? Thanks.

Comment: i did post THE WHOLE JSON from first,its the whole json which i receive on response from server

Comment: The JSON you posted is broken.

Comment: @JackStone, scroll to the right on your json line. You'll notice that the list is not closed properly.

Comment: ille edit it right now

Comment: how about a smaller sample?

Comment: here i did edit thats is all i do receive nothing more

Comment: The JSON is still broken

Comment: wait  wait,is it means that problem might be because json file not closed properly?

Comment: its how i do receive json...it means the guy who sent json to me,sent wrong?

Comment: maybe this web site could help you: http://jsonlint.com/ , it's a JSON syntax validator

Comment: If you have 11 objects in your array then this is not whole JSON. If possible then post your url.

Comment: problem is that its the whole json array i do receive,and i manually counted the array it only have 9 elements,not 11 for sure,but i guess the guy who sent the json array sent wrong...he isnt here so i must wait till tommorow to ask him,and i cant post url as its not public and it works only on my post request with certain parameters

Comment: i just tried validater,and it gave some error which i dont understand,so the guy must see it,ill keep updated about how it goes,hope its wrong from him not from me :D

Comment: Actually if you are printing your json in logcat then you can't see whole json if is long. So either write your json in file or use google chrome extension postman to view json using header parameters.